# How to delete files from Prefetch or such folders, which requires Administrative Permissions, programmatically via C#

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I am building a Windows Form application on C# which would list all files present in Prefetch, Temp and %temp% directory of windows installation and finally would delete them. But I am stuck as at the point where my app is not able to handle below exception. Please help me suggesting the best solution to achieve my goal.

"System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Prefetch' is denied.'"

My code for windows form app is below

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ZAP_CLEANER
{
     public partial class UC_FullScan : UserControl
     {
         public UC_FullScan()
         {
           InitializeComponent();
         }

   
         private void ibtn_StartScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            string rootPath = @"C:\Windows\Prefetch";
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(rootPath);
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(rootPath);
            foreach (string dir in dirs)
            {
                File.SetAttributes(dir, FileAttributes.Normal);
                textBox1.Text += dir;
            }
           foreach (string file in files)
            {
                File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
                textBox1.Text += file;
            }
      }

    public void DeleteDirectory(string targetDir)
    {
        File.SetAttributes(targetDir, FileAttributes.Normal);

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(targetDir);
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDir);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
            File.Delete(file);
        }

        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            DeleteDirectory(dir);
        }

        Directory.Delete(targetDir, false);
     }

     private void ibtn_Clean_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        string rootPath = @"C:\Windows\Prefetch";
        DeleteDirectory(rootPath);
     }
  }
}
```

[image: Exception unhandled]

Comment: The error message means exactly what it says.  You're being denied access to that folder for security reasons.  You could try logging in as an administrator.

Comment: Well as a matter of fact I am logged in as an administrator.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're out of luck.  It would appear that Microsoft reserves that folder exclusively for the operating system.

Comment: Alright, However I am wondering how Ccleaner (https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner/download) or such type of applications are implementing the same.

Comment: I don't really know how Windows handles administrator users, but is it possible you need to explicitly run your application with administrator privileges (even if you're logged in as an admin user)?